# How to change function of Linux USB composite gadget?

Tags: linux, usb

We need to be able to change the mass storage function in a Linux composite USB gadget (to change the mounted directory). Currently the scripts teardown the UDC and restart it with the changed mount point.

The problem with this is that it disconnects the ACM device providing the command/control serial connection with a Windows PC.

Is there a way to just takedown/restart the mass storage portion of the composite device without stopping the entire UDC?

This is with kernel 4.1.9.